# Is a maximal-square-covering unique?

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry, rectangles

Let X be a shape in 2-dimensional space.

Define a *square covering* of X as a set of axis-aligned squares, whose union exactly equals X.

Note that some shapes don't have a finite square covering, for example, a circle or a triangle.

Define a *maximal square covering* of X as a square covering where each square is needed, i.e.:

- For every square, there is a point in X that is covered by that square only.
- No two squares can be replaced by a larger square that is contained in X.

Is a maximal square covering, defined in this way, unique? (i.e. can there be two different maximal square coverings of the same shape?)

Comment: Are the squares necessarily parallel to the axes?

Comment: yes, the squares are axis-aligned, I edited the question

Comment: Doesn't even matter - my counterexample below *is* axis-aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q(a,b,c,d)$ denote the square having $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ as opposite vertices.
Then 
$$ \begin{align}X&=Q(-10,1,10,21)\cup Q(-10,-21,10,-1)\cup Q(-2,-1,2,3)\\& = Q(-10,1,10,21)\cup Q(-10,-21,10,-1)\cup Q(-2,-3,2,1)\end{align}$$
shows that uniqueness does not hold.

Comment: I see, you have a shape like a sandclock, with large squares at the top and bottom, and a short "neck" connecting them. The covering can include a square where the "neck" is either at the top or at the bottom, while the rest of the square overlaps one of the large squares. Thanks!